# What is the correct syntax to push multiple .xml files to an API from a folder, excluding the master xml file using a batch-file?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file which will push multiple .xml files to another API from one folder but excluding the master xml file, I was looking into below code to make this working but when I try to run the script nothing happen & syntax is also not looking good.

```
for /f %i (C:\temp\myfolder\*.xml) do (push.exe post %i actions)
```

it should do something like -

```
push.exe post C:\temp\myfolder\file1.xml actions
push.exe post C:\temp\myfolder\file2.xml actions
push.exe post C:\temp\myfolder\file3.xml actions
```

and so on...

Comment: The code snippet you have submitted will not work in a batch file. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should find out why in the first few lines of output.